# Core Dump em C. Acesso à Memória

Tags: dump

Ao executar o seguinte código, consigo digitar o nome e idade dos três primeiros funcionários e depois me é retornado o erro Core Dump. Pelo que li em https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/core-dump-segmentation-fault-c-cpp/, isso significa que estou tentando acessar um endereço de memória que não me pertence. Mas não consigo entender por que o mesmo não me pertence e por que consigo digitar os três primeiros.
Podem me ajudar pf?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct DADO
{
    char iNome[40];
    int iIdade;
};

int main(){

    struct DADO sDados[5];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite o nome do %d o funcionario: \n",i);
        scanf("%s",sDados[i].iNome);
        printf("Digita a idade do %d o funcionario: \n",i);
        scanf("%s",sDados[i].iIdade);
    }

    for(i=0; i<5 ; i++){
        printf("Funcionario: %s , Idade: %d", sDados[i].iNome, sDados[i].iIdade);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você declarou `iIdade` como `int` e portanto deve utilizar: `scanf("%d",&sDados[i].iIdade);`.

Comment: Verdade! Não tinha notado que o scanf da idade estava para receber string (%s)! Obrigado!